# How to prevent autoresizing UINavigationBar on Landscape

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, landscape

In generally, on the landscape mode, the navigation bar controlled by navigation controller automatically reduce its size smaller.

But I want to prevent that autoresizing.

First, I set the navigation bar hidden and used another navigation bar not controlled by navigation controller. So, I solved the problem. But I want to find the way to disable autoresizing the navigation bar on landscape without using another bar not controlled by navigation controller.

Comment: why do you want to do this? this is standard iOS behavior.

Comment: @nielsbot Take a look at iOS 7 Safari in landscape ;)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by creating a category on UINavigationBar:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customHeight)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,44);
    return newSize;
}

@end
```

With the category created, the height now stays fixed at 44 - I don't even need to import the category anywhere.

My app uses storyboards but I'm pretty sure it would work either way.

Comment: While this solves the issue, it's not good practice to try and use categories for method overriding purposes. You should do this in a subclass. Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: this solution works for the navigation bar, but it moves my toolbar up 10px or so from the bottom of the view...

Comment: This causes the elements in the bar to no longer be vertically centered. Any way to resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

This will work for iOS 8

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    public override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var newSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 44)
        return newSize
    }
}
```

Comment: Please educate the asker and all of us by shortly explaining _how and why_ it works. That way, you can hope to get an upvote not only by jinbruce627, but also from other users.