# Navigation bar in UINavigationController too short

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm putting together an app where some of the views are in regular UIViewControllers and use their own UINavigationBar, whereas others will be part of a navigation hierarchy inside a UINavigationController and make use of its UINavigationBar instead.

The problem is that the actual UINavigationBars that I'm seeing are different in these two cases. The ones in that use a UINavigationController's navigation bar seem unnaturally short. Here are some pictures, showing what I see in Interface Builder versus what I see at runtime.

[image: A view in a regular view controller, which has its own navigation bar]
[image: A UINavigationController + content view controller setup]
[image: The first view in the simulator]
[image: The second view in the simulator -- note the way-too-short navigation bar!]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Why are the navigation bars different heights? How can I make them the same?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Looks like I am looking at Navigation bar vs uitoolbar in some of the pictures.

Comment: Sam, there are no UIToolbar objects involved here. 

The "Reviews" screen is presented as a modal dialog, so I wanted a title bar and a button to dismiss, so I used a UINavigationBar directly in the view. The "Done" button is a UIBarButtonItem.

In the "Menu" screen, I have a hierarchy of screens to present, so I create a UINavigationController, which of course has its own built-in UINavigationBar. 

So, in a nutshell, in what for me is the most vanilla way to use a UINavigationController, the navigation bar is too short.

Comment: @SamBudda (Forgot to mention your username in the last post and it's too late to edit.)

Comment: the existing behavior is intended and is standard iOS behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was going on here. UINavigationController resizes the navigation bar in portrait orientation automatically, and as far as I can tell, there is no built-in way to prevent this from happening. However, with the help of this post ([How to prevent autoresizing UINavigationBar on Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023408/how-to-prevent-autoresizing-uinavigationbar-on-landscape)), I was able to get it working the way I wanted. My code was slightly different from the code in the linked post. I used:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomHeight)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    // Need to know the width of the window
    CGRect bounds = self.window.bounds;

    // Sometimes height and width are turned around. Take the largest of height and width as the real width.
    int width = (bounds.size.width > bounds.size.height) ? bounds.size.width : bounds.size.height;

    // Make sure that the 
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, 44);
    return newSize;
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to get the true width - the above is clunky but works for me since my app only runs in landscape. My bigger concern is that Apple says in its UINavigationBar documentation that you shouldn't directly adjust the frame. But I guess I'm not directly doing that; presumably internal drawing methods will call this method and do their thing.

Anyway, this works for me. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You should not adjust the nav bar height. It's standard iOS behavior to adjust it's height in wide screen orientation. (It's intentionally 44 points in portrait and less in landscape.) Why do you want to do this?

Comment: just check any of Apple's apps to see what I'm talking about. If you are customizing the nav bar, you should provide a less-tall version for wide screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @nielsbot. I'm definitely on-board with the idea that one shouldn't try to manipulate the OS-provided widgets beyond what they are designed for. In this particular case, it's mainly to provide a unified experience. I have two other screens that are conceptually siblings of the one I am trying to modify, and these use a UINavigationBar that is not presented in a UINavigationController. The OS is showing these with the tall (44 pt) size. So it looks a little funny to have two screens with the tall bar and one with the short one.

Comment: How do the other screens appear? Sounds like you have a navigation hierarchy--shouldn't all the views be presented inside view controllers added to the navigation stack?

Comment: You can see the two kinds of screens in the images in my first post. The Reviews screen does not contain a navigation stack. It's just a modal screen that uses a UINavigationBar for the purpose of dismissing the screen. Without any interference from me, the OS displays this bar at 44px. The Menu screen is indeed the first page of a navigation hierarchy, and so it uses the UINavigationController with its integrated UINavigationBar, and the OS displays this bar at 32px. These two screens are presented by buttons right next to each other in the UI, so it feels weird that they look different.

Comment: ah.. well, you could place a navigation controller in your modal sheet, but add just a single view controller to it. (vs using a standalone `UINavigationBar`)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's probably the approach that's most in the spirit of the official design. Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

I truly believe you are mixing up two different features. UINaviationbar and UIToolbar. Here is apple's human guidelines. Look at the top of the document for Navigation Bar

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41

I will try to see if I can find a document on their dimensions. Here is one. I am sure there are better ones available

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html